# $stateProvider not working under sub-routes

Tags: angularjs

I want to go for `banks.loan_plans.edit` state from `banks.loan_plans` state.

However, When I click the blue button. The url changed from

> http://dev.co/admin.html#/banks/101/loan_plans/

to

> http://dev.co/admin.html#/banks/101/loan_plans/edit/101/8

However, it stills remain in the same state and controller.

The `loanPlanEditCtrl` was not triggered

[image: inline]

## HTML for the button link button

```
<a ui-sref="banks.loan_plans.edit({bank_id:bank_id, loan_plan_id: plan.id})">
    <button class="btn btn-info ">Edit</button>
</a>
```

## $stateProvider

```
  .state('banks', {
      url: '/banks',
      template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in"></div>',
      resolve: load(['js/services/bank.js', 'js/controllers/banks.js'])
  })
  .state('banks.loan_plans', {
      url: '/:bank_id/loan_plans',
      controller: 'loanPlanBaseCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'admin_tpl/loan_plan/index.html',
      resolve: load(['js/controllers/loan_plan.js'])
  })
  .state('banks.loan_plans.edit', {
      url: '/edit/:bank_id/:loan_plan_id',
      controller: 'loanPlanEditCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'admin_tpl/loan_plan/form.html',
  })
```

## Parent state's HTML

```
<div ui-view class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="loanPlanIndexCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>LowerRate</td>
                    <td>HigherRate</td>
                    <td>Operation</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat=" plan in loan_plans ">
                    <td>
                        {{ plan.name || 'empty' }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ plan.description || 'empty' }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ plan.lowerbound_rate || 'empty' }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ plan.upperbound_rate || 'empty' }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a ui-sref="admin.banks.loan_plans.edit({bank_id:bank_id, loan_plan_id: plan.id})">
                            <button class="btn btn-info ">Edit</button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## Child states' HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="loanPlanEditCtrl">        
  I'm child
</div>
```

Comment: Are you linked to the controller in the html?

Comment: any errors in the console? Can you see the form.html template or the loanPlanEditCtrl file being loaded from the server?

Comment: @Chris he's linked through the routing config, no need to link again in the html

Comment: If you have a child state, the parent template must have a `ui-view` directive inside it - I.E. if you don't want a state to be rendered *within* another state's template, it can't be a child state (at least, that's how it works by default, there may be a way around it).

Comment: If the controller is in a separate file, he'll still have to link to it.

Comment: @ChrisStanley yes, i did `<div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="loanPlanIndexCtrl"> and <div class="wrapper-md" ng-controller="loanPlanEditCtrl">
` for each html files

Comment: @JoeClay I've updated my post, however, the ui-view not works as well

Comment: @JoeClay by the way, there is already a grandparent state with `          template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in"></div>',
`

Comment: @newBike - That's the point I'm trying to make (although I phrased it pretty badly...) - any state that has children needs a `ui-view` in its template. Having `ui-view` in the grandparent state will render the parent state, but you need *another* `ui-view` directive in your parent state to render the child. It sounds to me like you might be better off renaming `banks.loan_plans.edit` to `banks.loan_plans_edit` - that way, it'll be a child of the `banks` state instead, and will take the place of `banks.loan_plans` when you navigate to it. The URL can stay the same, though.